# How to execute an already compiled jar while building my project in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am developing a library and I need to automatically generate a .java file before compiling. I found out a the `maven-exec-plugin` and I configured it in this way

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-city-enum</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>java</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <mainClass>org.codeforamerica.open311.city_enum_builder.EnumBuilder</mainClass>
        <arguments>
          <argument>-jar</argument>
          <argument>city_enum_builder.jar</argument>
          <argument>cities.json</argument>
          <arguments>output.java</arguments>
        </arguments>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

The problem is that running `mvn -e compile` I get the following error:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codeforamerica.open311.city_enum_builder.EnumBuilder`

However, this is the main class, and, indeed, if I execute `java -cp .:city_enum_builder.jar org.codeforamerica.open311.city_enum_builder.EnumBuilder cities.json output.java` it works.

In addition, this .jar doesn't need to specify a class in order to get executed (`java -jar city_enum_builder.jar cities.json output.java` works as well).

Thank you.

Comment: is `city_enum_builder.jar` in your classpath when executing `mvn -e compile`?

Comment: It is in the project's root folder (from where I execute `mvn`). I followed the approach from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15282659/986257). Which just provides the .jar path, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you confuse the parameters for the `exec:exec` goal (which spawns an external process) with `exec:java` (which just executes some Java class in Mavens VM).

(So for your example, `<executable>java</executable>` will be ignored (so no java.exe called) and obviously your class itself doesnt know how to resolve classpaths.

So add the project providing your city_enum_builder.jar as dependency to your `exec-maven-plugin` and it should work.

And dont forget to check http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html for more details.