# How to execute a maven goal described in a pom.xml file packaged in a jar

Tags: maven

I have a maven project which generated a jar with its pom file inside and this jar is deployed on different environment. pretty straightfoward for the moment.

I would like to execute a goal (a liquibase:update) from this pom file using only the jar produced. Is there a way to do this automatically  with maven, without extracting the files from the jar beforehand ? Something like `mvn -jar myJar.jar liquibase:update`

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer to this question, I think it can help you:

[Is there a good way to use maven to run an executable jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148044/is-there-a-good-way-to-use-maven-to-run-an-executable-jar)

Comment: Sadly, not. It is not really the same context. Shaun want to execute the jar from the module source directory. I want to execute the jar directly, without having access to the module source.